# How to Append Comment When "Send Tracking Information" is Clicked

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, email, shipment-tracking

After an order is shipped with the tracking number another button appears "Send Tracking Information". If clicked it resends the tracking email to customer.  But one doesn't get the checkbox to append a comment to the email.

How can one append comment to these tracking emails?